# In a feedforward neural network, am I able to put in a feature input of "don't care"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I've created a feedforward neural network using DL4J in Java.

Hypothetically and to keep things simple, assume this neural network is a binary classifier of squares and circles.

The input, a feature vector, would be composed of say... 5 different variables:

```
[number_of_corners,
number_of_edges,
area,
height,
width]
```

Now so far, my binary classifier can tell the two shapes apart quite well as I'm giving it a complete feature vector.

My question: is it possible to input only maybe 2 or 3 of these features?  Or even 1?  I understand results will be less accurate while doing so, I just need to be able to do so.

If it is possible, how?

How would I do it for a neural network with 213 different features in the input vector?

Comment: Do you have a scenario where you have some data vectors with missing features?

Comment: all data used to train, validate and test the neural network is fully complete, as in all features in the input vector are present and have meaningful values.

however, another possible use case for my network does involve classifying data for which certain fields are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume, for example, that you know the `area`, `height`, and `width` features (so you don't know the `number_of_corners` and `number_of_edges` features).

If you know that a shape can have, say, a maximum of 10 corners and 10 edges, you could input 10 feature vectors with the same area, height and width but where each vector has a different value for the `number_of_corners` and `number_of_edges` features. Then you can just average over the 10 outputs of the network and round to the nearest integer (so that you still get a binary value).

Similarly, if you only know the `area` feature you could average over the outputs of the network given several random combinations of input values, where the only fixed value is the `area` and all the others vary. (I.e. the `area` feature is the same for each vector but every other feature has a random value.)

This may be a "trick" but I think that the average will converge to a value as you increase the number of (almost-)random vectors.

## Edit

My solution would not be a good choice if you have a lot of features. In this case you could try to use maybe a Deep Belief Network or some autoencoder to infer the values of the other features given a small number of them. For example, a DBN can "reconstruct" a noisy output (if you train it enough, of course); you could then try to give the reconstructed input vector to your feed-forward network.

Comment: this solution can work for simple neural networks like the one i have described.  how would one do it for a more complex neural network where the computational complexity makes things near impossible?

for example, my actual neural network is a binary classifier based on 213 different features with values on some of the features being essentially boolean (0, 1) while others are doubles in the order of anywhere between 0 to 7 digits long

Comment: If the input vectors are more complex, then I'm afraid that the only way to implement my solution is to increase the number of input evaluations, if you want to get a good average.

Comment: So in the case of 213 features, chances are that my solution is not a good one :)

Comment: inferring values of other features given N out of M total number of features is pretty much exactly what i want to do.  would a dbn work well for binary classification? given my variables are completely numeric continuous numbers that have been normalized between 0 and 1, what would i fill the other vectors with to avoid a NullPointerException? the average value for that field?

Comment: DBNs are not meant for classification but rather for "reconstruction" (you can say that a DBN is a _generative_ model, while a feed-forward net is a _discriminative_ model -- try to google those terms for more about that). But, after having generated a reconstruction of your input, you can pass it to your binary classifier. Thus you would have: [input vector] -> DBN -> [reconstructed input vector] -> FFNN -> binary result

Comment: For the second question in your comment, I would fill the missing values with random floats picked from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1 (that is: random values between 0 and 1)

Comment: perfect, i will try this and hopefully it all works out.

i appreciate the help greatly - marked as answer

Comment: Great, I hope this works. Also, I'm not sure but maybe you could replace the DBN with the "candidate-elimination" algorithm or some other network/algorithm.. I think it all depends on the degree of correlation between the features of your input (i.e. it depends upon how much a feature depends on the others). In general, I would try to explore many machine learning techniques and select the best one. Good luck!